# What are the uppercase and lowercase rules of ruby method name?

Tags: ruby

I am a Ruby beginner. From the book, I know that a Ruby method name should start with a lowercase letter or underscore. But I found different scenarios:

1. If a method is defined outside a class, it can only begin with lowercase letter, Ruby will complain with an error if you try to define a method which begins with an uppercase letter, for example:

   ```
   define sayHi
     puts "Hello" 
   end
   sayHi   # => Hello
   ```

   but, the following code does not work:

   ```
   define SayHi
     puts "Hello" 
   end
   SayHi
   ```

   it will produce an error:

   ```
   :in `<main>': uninitialized constant SayHi (NameError)
   ```
2. If a method is defined inside a class, then it can begin with uppercase letter:

   ```
   class Test
     def SayHi
       puts "hello" 
     end
   end
   t = Test.new
   t.SayHi    # => hello
   ```

Does anyone know why #1 does not work while #2 work? What are the exact rules the ruby method name?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

By convention, things that start with uppercase letters are *constants*. When you invoke `SayHi`, you're telling Ruby to look for a *constant with this name*. Of course, there isn't one, so it fails.

If you want to invoke the method, you'll need to add a pair of parentheses. For example,

```
def S
  puts "shazam!"
end

S    #=> NameError: uninitialized constant S
S()  #=> "shazam!"
```

Inside of a class, the resolution rules are a little different. Let's define a simple class with a constant and a method named to look like a constant:

```
irb(main):001:0> class C
irb(main):002:1>   A = "x"
irb(main):003:1>   def B
irb(main):004:2>     puts "B() invoked"
irb(main):005:2>   end
irb(main):006:1> end
=> nil
```

Now, `A` is certainly a constant. But what about `B`?

```
irb(main):008:0> C.const_defined?("A")
=> true    # A is a constant!
irb(main):009:0> C.const_defined?("B")
=> false   # B looks like a constant but isn't, because we
           # used "def" to create it. "def" is for methods,
           # not constants.
```

So it isn't a constant, just a method with that name. When we try to access `B` from an instance of `C`, now Ruby's looking for a method:

```
irb(main):011:0> C.new.B
B() invoked
=> nil
```

If we wanted to access a constant of `C` instead, we use the scope qualifier `::`:

```
irb(main):012:0> C::A
=> "x"
```

Comment: Fairly new to ruby, and this is helpful to me as well. Excellently explained. +1

Comment: "By convention", nope, by rule, because Ruby enforces it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do any of what you're trying to do.  It's bad coding style.

Good Ruby coding style:

```
def method_name
end

# or

class CamelCase
  def method_name(parameter_name)
  end
end
```

Almost anything else is simply wrong.  The language might let you do other stuff, but that doesn't mean you should.

Also, generally you don't want to be defining methods outside of a class or module — that's acceptable in short throw-away scripts, but not in projects of substance.

Comment: Maybe emend "outside of a class" to "outside of a class or module"? Not *everything* makes sense in a class - sometimes you have a bundle of methods that fit together, but you have no reason to make instances for those methods.

Comment: Actually, methods that begin with uppercase letters are quite common and even part of the core libraries and standard libraries, for example the `Array` method, `Hash`, `Integer`, `Float`, `String` in the core library and `DelegateClass` in the `delegate` library. It is not at all "bad coding style", quite the opposite actually. It's actually the proper way to define methods which return `Class` es or `Module` s, which are then intended to be `include` d, `extend` ed or inherited from.

Comment: True, but let's be clear though, those are not common use-cases.  This is a new guy, and he's no going to be writing methods that return classes or modules anytime soon.  While I've used a few of those, I don't think I've yet found a good reason to write one myself.

Comment: Hi, Mr Adam, that is true that I am new guy for Ruby, I already know it is not a good coding convention, I want to clarify that  I am not trying to do the 'bad coding style', but I am trying to understand the reason behind it. If the statement of what you mentioned about 'bad style' is true, then it should not be allowed to use anywhere in ruby, and there should be no reason to make exception to break the bad style because it is bad style. But unfortunately it is not true.

Comment: Ruby doesn't hold your hand — it assumes you're an adult, and you know what you're doing.  Even Python doesn't do this.