# What is the difference between these two ruby functions?

Tags: ruby, irb

Function GetTitle when called from ruby shell throws an error
 **"uninitialized constant GetTitle"**

While full_title is working fine.

What is the problem with the GetTitle?

```
def GetTitle(pageTitle = '')
  baseTitle = "Base Title"
  if pageTitle.empty?
    baseTitle
  else
    pageTitle + " | " + baseTitle
  end
end

def full_title(page_title = '')
  base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  if page_title.empty?
    base_title
  else
    page_title + " | " + base_title
  end
end
```

Comment: Functions should be all lowercased, as the capital letters are reserved for classes and constants.

Comment: Words (including underscores) that begin with a capital letter refer to constants. Recognizing that classes are modules, "Defining a module creates a constant with the same name as the module. The value of this constant is the `Module` object that represents the module". (Source: *The Ruby Programming Language* by  Flanagan and Matsumoto, p. 249.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ruby, as per convention, constants begin with an uppercase letter. So when you call `GetTitle` its being treated as a constant and you get appropriate error (since there is no such constant). However if you call it with a parameter, it will work. This is because of the presence of parameter Ruby is interpreting it as a method. Here:

```
GetTitle
# NameError: uninitialized constant GetTitle
GetTitle('abc')
#=> "abc | Base Title"
```

You can make Ruby believe its a method by using empty parenthesis too:

```
GetTitle()
#=> "Base Title"
```

[This answer explains it beautifully](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2032004/3035830).